# Start process with QUARTZ.NET

Tags: c#, process, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

This is method in my `.NET` console application `program.cs` class

```
public static void Run()
    {

        var isRunning = false;
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        Startup startup = new Startup();
        var serviceProvider = startup.ConfigureServices(services);
        IWindsorContainer _container = 
        DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!isRunning)
            {
                isRunning = true;
                var configuration = _container.Resolve<IConfigurationRoot>();
                var _process = _container.Resolve<Process.Process>();
                var cron = (configuration[Enums.ExecutionTime]);

                if (thisDay == DateTime.Now)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        _process.MainProcess();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        isRunning = false;
                        Thread.Sleep(secondsForSleep);
                        _container.Release(_process);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use [quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/index.html) for starting `_process.MainProcess()`
However all examples I can find are with starting `Jobs` does anyone know if it supports starting process or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: on a sidenote, `if (thisDay == DateTime.Now)` will only be true at exactly midnight, is that really the intended behaviour?

Comment: I will not leave this if there if I find how to start process with `quartz.net`

Answer (score 2):

You simply implement the `IJob` interface and have the job run the process:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyProcessJob : IJob
{     
    private readonly Process _process;

    public MyProcessJob(Process process)
    {
        _process = process;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _process.MainProcess();
    }
}
```

Job creation and scheduling is well explained in the [Quartz.NET quick start guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html).